# Is it possible to complete transaction after throwing and start new one in Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jta, spring-transactions

I have a controller marked with Transactional annotation. Method *join* may throw exception, that I'm handling by method *handle* with help of @ExceptionHandler annotation.

```
public String join(Model uiModel) {
  ... here exception occures
}

@ExceptionHandler(BalanceException.class)
public String handle() {
    return "someView";
}
```

When *handle* method returns name of a view, then everything is fine. Unfortunately I need to make a redirect to another controller, that requires transaction.

Is it possible to complete this transaction and start new one ?

Comment: If this were pure SQL, you could use "checkpoints".  It doesn't look like Spring supports checkpoints: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.7/reference/transaction.html

Comment: @paulsm4 that's version 2.0.x. Spring is currently at version 3.1.x, so you might check a newer version (these are 5 years old)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should never start a transaction in the view layer, but use the service layer to handle transactional logic. That means you should use the @Transactional annotation on your Spring beans in the service layer.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't help the OP solve the problem: to get a transaction from request to redirect.